# iPhone simulators don't match Xcode preview

Tags: ios, iphone, xcode, ios-simulator

My word wrapping UILabel appears as expected in Xcode's new preview feature. However when launching on different sized iPhone simulators, the word wrapping is always at the same point:

[image: Xcode preview]

[image: iPhone 4s (matches preview)]

[image: iPhone 6 Plus (doesn't match preview, looks same as 4s)]

Why doesn't launching this in the simulator match the preview?

Comment: You don't seem to have the iPhone 6/6+ launch images and/or "launch screen file".

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is because you have not "enabled" your app for iPhone 6 and 6+ device sizes.

You will notice that when you start the app on the iPhone 6+ simulator the status bar is a lot bigger in your app than when in the home screen. This is because it just uses the interface for the smaller device and scales it up to be the size of the bigger device.

To "enable" it you need to add a launch image for the iPhone 6 and 6+ sizes.

You can do this either with your asset catalog or by using a launch interface file.